# BASH variable values as new defined variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I don't know exactly how to ask this in English, but I want to have the value of a variable as a new variable...
The script also has a loop with increasing numbers, and in the end I want to have the variables VAR1, VAR2 etc.

I'm trying this:

```
COUNT=$(echo 1)
DEFINE=$(echo VAR$COUNT)
$DEFINE=$(echo gotcha!)
```

When I try this way, I have this error message:

```
~/script.sh: line n: VAR1=gotcha!: command not found
```

I played a bit around with brackets and quotation marks, but it didn't work... any solutions?

Comment: The question is tagged with `bash`.  Why aren't you instead using `bash` arrays?

Comment: Why are you using `echo` in a command substitution? this is really silly. Use this instead: `count=1`, `define=var$count`. Now for the last one, you may use `printf -v "$define" '%s' 'gotcha!'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `declare` to create such a "dynamic" variable, but using an array is probably a better choice.

```
COUNT=1
DEFINE="VAR$COUNT"
declare "$DEFINE=gotcha"
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my SPECIFIC problem completely. Also thanks to all other contributors. As a neophyte, i'm surely gonna fall in love with StackOverflow ^^.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that bash expects a command as a result of expansions, not an assignment. `VAR1=gotcha!` is not a command, hence the error.

It would be better to use an array:

```
COUNT=$(echo 1)
VAR[COUNT]='gotcha!'
echo ${VAR[COUNT]}
```

I guess `$(echo 1)` stands for a more complex command, otherwise you can just use `COUNT=1`.